# Updating a treeview from other usercontrol using delegate in C#

Tags: c#, forms, delegates, user-controls, treeview

In a main form I have a treeview control where each node calls a different user control in a panel present in the main form. My problem is that one of these user controls is responsible to add/delete/update nodes of the treeview in the main form.

I have tried to do it using delegates it is not working.

In the main form I have a method like this:

```
public void UpDateTreeView()
{
    //load xml file that contain my nodes
    //do something

    myTreeView.Refresh();
}
```

In the User Control I'm trying it:

```
delegate void UpDatingMyTreeView();

private void buttonUpDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //update the xml file with a new node
    //do something...

    frm_MainForm frm = new frm_MainForm frm();
    UpDatingMyTreeView updTrv = new UpDatingMyTreeView(frm.UpDateTreeView);
    updTrv();
}
```

I have never used delegates and it's not working. I'm using windows form application.

Comment: buttonUpDate_Click   in userControl or MainForm ? and MainForm is actived?

Comment: Main form is Parent User Control ?

Comment: The buttonUpDate_Click is in the User Control.

Comment: The main form is not a parent user control, it is just a form with a Panel.

Comment: Parent User Control  ?

Comment: I'm loading the User Control dynamically in the Panel Control in the form.

Comment: myTreeView in Main form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution starts when you can get the main form of the Uzur Control.
We use the following method:

```
yourUserControl.FindForm(); or this.FindForm();
```

Then we do the next projection to get the **Main form** of **Instance** .

```
private void buttonUpDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ((MainForm)this.FindForm()).UpDateTreeView();
    }
```

UpDateTreeView() is public  Method  in MainForm .